# How to unlock a G1

Tags: sim-unlocking, htc-dream

Yes, I got the G1 the day it was launched in the UK. Swapped it for HTC Desire when that was launched. Now have a Galaxy S4.

Anyway, I moved away from T-Mobile without removing the G1's network lock (because I was using the Desire then). Lately, I've been experimenting a bit and would like to use the G1 for some things.

How can I unlock it?

Comment: go back to the original mobile provider where you got the G1 from and ask for the unlock code (charges may apply)

Comment: @t0mm13b Thanks, but I was looking for a more technical, DIY answer.

Answer (score 0):

HTC starting offering their own free [unlock tool](http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/) online some little while ago in an effort to be more hack-friendly, and the G1 (or Dream) is one of the phones you can unlock with it.  Failing that you can also contact HTC support to get the unlock code.

Answer (score -1):

If you wish you can check with online unlocking service provider called [Mobile-Unlocker.com](http://www.mobile-unlocker.com/t-mobile-g1/rs16wp9/) who will help you in unlocking your G1 within 1-2 working days...